# View controller and partial view controller method accessibility

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What should the accessibility (`public`, `private`, etc) be for the controller method for a View and a Partial View?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ????? ActionResult MyView(...) { ... }

    ????? PartialViewResult MyPartialView(...) { ... }
}
```

Presumably, as the View will be accessed from outside then it needs to be `public`, but partial views, which are used only within the context of the controller, do these also have to be `public`?

Or is it a requirement - due to routing - that they both need to be `public`?

Comment: depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PartialViews` are re-useable, for now you may not require to use it but later at sometime you main need to use it from different views. I would suggest you to make these action public, but if you want to restrict users to directly access these views then you can use `[NonAction]` attribute:

```
[NonAction]  
public PartialViewResult MyPartialView(...) { ... }
```